# How do I stop cpan from reconfiguring each time? + More

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm running on a Mac (version 10.6.3) and am struggling to understand what is going on with my Perl installation.

I let the system do a copy from my previous mac, and I appear to have a second perl installed, which appears earlier in my path. I can't tell (or remember) if I might have installed it with fink, macports or CPAN or what.

```
type -a cpan
cpan is /opt/local/bin/cpan
cpan is /usr/bin/cpan
```

I'm seeing two oddities. (To start with!) When I run cpan, and let it configure in ~lcuff/.cpan, each time I run it, it wants to reconfigure, giving the message:

Sorry, we have to rerun the configuration dialog for CPAN.pm due to
some missing parameters...

Also, when I try to install File::Find::Rule (so I can list my CPAN modules, per the FAQ) I end up with an error message that I can't decipher or Google a solution for:

```
Use of inherited AUTOLOAD for non-method Digest::SHA::shaopen() is deprecated at /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level/Digest/SHA.pm line 55.
Catching error: "Can't locate auto/Digest/SHA/shaopen.al in \@INC (\@INC contains: /sw/lib/perl5 /sw/lib/perl5/darwin /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9 /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9 /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9 /Users/lcuff) at /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level/Digest/SHA.pm line 55\cJ" at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/CPAN.pm line 359
    CPAN::shell() called at /opt/local/bin/cpan line 198
```

Comment: If I had this problem I would deinstall and reinstall.

Comment: `/opt/local` is macports.  When you run `o conf` the first line should say `$CPAN::Config options from ...`.  What does that say?  I suspect this is an issue with File::HomeDir changing the CPAN shell's idea of where it should store your configuration.  What version of the CPAN shell is this?

Comment: @Snake: agreed: nuke it from orbit, it's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through my first migration to a new Mac last week, including a switch from fink and system `perl` to MacPorts and custom `perl`, so I remember the pain all too well...

As Schwern said, `/opt/local` is the default install location for MacPorts; fink uses `/sw`.

I did encounter a similar problem with CPAN configuration, although I didn't make any attempt to determine whether it was repeatable or not.

The first time I ran CPAN config, it said that I had an existing CPAN dir at `~/.cpan` and stored the configuration there.

The second time, it wanted to configure into an existing CPAN dir at `~/Library/Application Support/.cpan`.  I didn't feel like repeating the CPAN configuration, so I broke out, did a quick `cd ~/Library/Application Support/.cpan ; rm -rf .cpan ; ln -s ~/.cpan .`, and it's worked great for me since then.

Hopefully this will at least help get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`Perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/).

Perlbrew allows you to install and manage mulitple versions for Perl under your home directory at `~/perl5`

Installation is easy:

```
 curl -LO http://xrl.us/perlbrew
 chmod +x perlbrew
 ./perlbrew install
```

and simply follow the instructions.

Been using it for past few months on Mac OSX and it worked like a charm!

/I3az/